# How can I call this function in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have a type function like this

```
function :: Eq a => a -> (b -> c -> a) -> b -> [(d,c)] -> Bool
```

But I cannot call it. Can anyone give me an example: for example function a b c with an example?

Comment: it might be helpful if you can describe what this function does and what each of its argument means..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have somewhat complicated function that checks for a membership in an association list using a helper function.

The function you provided:

```
function :: Eq a => a -> (b -> c -> a) -> b -> [(d,c)] -> Bool
```

Takes three arguments:

- an element to compare `a`,
- a helper function `b -> c -> a`,
- an argument for the helper function `b`,
- a list of tuples `[(d, c)]`.

Then, one possible function of the type you provided is:

```
function :: Eq a => a -> (b -> c -> a) -> b -> [(d,c)] -> Bool
function a f b ((_,c):rest) = ((f b c) == a) || (function a f b rest
function a f b rest         = False
```

Which checks for an membership in the list, by ignoring the first element of the tuple and applying the helper function to the second argument of the tuple.

While the function may seem complicated, you could run it on a fairly simple example

```
function True (==) 0 [("a", 0), ("b",1)]
```

In the above example, we are looking for `0` using the `(==)` helper function, and we check if the helper function returns `True`.

Answer (score 1):

The type is so general that it's hard to reason about what the function actually does. However, since `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` have few constraints, let's provide an example where they all happen to satisfy `Int`:

```
function (3::Int) (+) 5 [(1,2), (3,4)]
```

The first argument has to be type `a`, with the only constraint being that it be an instance of `Eq`. `3 :: Int` satisfies that requirement.

The second argument just needs to be a two-argument function returning an `Int`. `(+)` satisfies that requirement, while fixing `b ~ c ~ Int` as well.

The third argument must be of type `b ~ Int` as well.

The last argument just needs to be a list of type `[(d, Int)`] for any type `d`. We'll just pass a list of pairs of `Int`s.